# Zend Framework can't find standard view helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I'm trying to use a View helper inside a view.
I put

```
echo $this->formCheckbox('foo');
```

in the view, but it errors out and tells me `FormCheckbox.php`

> /application/modules/user/views/helpers/FormCheckbox.php can't be
>   found.

Why isn't it loading `Zend_View_Helper_FormCheckbox` in `/Zend/View/Helper?` The manual states

> The default helper path always points
>   to the Zend Framework view helpers,
>   i.e., 'Zend/View/Helper/'. Even if you
>   call setHelperPath() to overwrite the
>   existing paths, this path will be set
>   to ensure the default helpers work.

Comment: Can you post your view initialisation/bootstrap code?

Comment: http://www.pastebin.ca/1701783, and I have nothing in my bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

To use helpers in my views I use:

```
<?= $this->LinkTo('css/general/screen.css'); ?>
```

Is your helper 'FormCheckbox' with a capital **F**?

Comment: In both cases, it looks for FormCheckbox.php with a capital F. All the standard helpers arent working, including LinkTo.